# Turn individual bits off in C

Tags: c

To set the lowest bit in an `unsigned char` I can perform this operation:

```
my_unsigned_char = my_unsigned_char | 1;
```

But how can I turn off this flag?

Comment: Mybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920307/how-can-i-remove-a-flag-in-c

Comment: If `1` turns it on, what would `&0xfe` do?

Answer (score 2):

Use the bitwise not operator:

```
my_unsigned_char = my_unsigned_char & ~1;
```