# How can I remove a bit flag in PHP int?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, flags

Let's say I have

```
$flags=JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;
```

How can I then remove JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES from `$flags`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the way to do it.

Comment: Rather than posting your own answer in the question body, split your question into both a question and own answer. If there are better alternatives around, those can then still be added and upvoted by others.

Comment: When writing a question, there is even a checkbox "Add your own answer"

Comment: See also [operators.bitwise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Comment: What's the point of this bitwise OR? What does `$flags` do?

Comment: @vivek_23 you can find the documentation for all of those flags at https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php - `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` tries to make the output look "pretty", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES makes it not escape slashes (by default `/` is escaped as `\/`, which is not required by JSON, but php does it anyway, which can optionally be turned off), `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` makes it add unicode characters in strings literally instead of adding a unicode escape character looking like \uXXXX)

Comment: `$flags` contains several bits of information in one number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not "C method" it's just applying [bitwise operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
$flags=JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;

var_dump($flags & JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); // flag should be set to 1

$flags &= ~JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES; // remove it  

var_dump($flags & JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); // flag should be set to 0
```

Answer (score 2):

using [the C method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3920427/1067003)

```
$flags &= ~JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES;
```

[seems to work.](https://3v4l.org/OtW05)

Comment: How about `$flags ^= JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES;` ?

Comment: `$flags ^= JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES;` only works when you know that the flag is currently set, but `$flags &= ~JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES;` works always to unset the flag.

Comment: @Adder Thanks. From the OP, it looked as if it was set already.

Comment: @vivek_23 `^` is xor which means it toggles the flag. If it was 1 it becomes 0 if it was 0 it becomes 1.

Comment: @Robert yes, just realized that. Thanks. Looking at the OP, I presumed it was already set.

Answer (score 0):

In case you **can't reach flags directly**, as their are added later in **3rd party code** (my case):

```
<?php

function notMyFunction($flags)
{
    $finalFlags = $flags | FLAG_I_DONT_WANT;
    // ...
}
```

There is this trick:

```
<?php


notMyFunction(FLAG_I_DONT_WANT - 1);
```